# Call the neighbor actors in the game of life using scala akka actor model

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm just beginner in scala but experienced in Java and C++, now I want to use akka actor model to implement the parallel Conway's Game of Life. My thought is create a 50*50 grid, each cell is an actor, and passing messages among actors to update. Here is the way I create the actors:

```
class World(row: Int, col: Int, step: Int) extends Actor {



val random = new Random() //generate the alive or dead cell for the game
  val cellgrid = new World(row, col, step)
  def receive = {

case Start => { 

  for(gridrow <- 0 until row) {
    for(gridcol <- 0 until col) {
      context.actorOf(Props(new Grid(random.nextBoolean, gridrow, gridcol, row, col, step)))
    }
  }

  for (gridrow <- 0 until row) {
    for (gridcol <- 0 until col) {
      sender ! Compare()
    }
  }

}

case Done(gridrow, gridcol, alive) => {
  for(gridrow <- 0 until row) {
    for(gridcol <- 0 until col) {
      if(alive) print("* ")
      else print("  ")
    }
    print("\n")
  }
  sender ! Stop
}

case Stop => {context.stop(self); println("Stopped the actor system!")}
case _ => context.stop(self)


 }
}
```

But that causes a problem. Since I create so many Grid classes, I'm having trouble call the neighbor  actors. Here is the Grid class:

```
class Grid(var life: Boolean, gridrow: Int, gridcol: Int, row: Int, col: Int, step: Int) extends Actor { 



val alive = life
  var numNeighbors = 0  
  var currentStep = 0
  val desiredSteps = step
  val count = Array(0,0)
  val countsuround = Array(0,0)

  for (neighbourX <- gridrow - 1 to gridrow + 1) {
    if (neighbourX >= 0 && neighbourX < col) {
      for (neighbourY <- gridcol - 1 to gridcol + 1) {
        if (neighbourY >= 0 && neighbourY < row && (neighbourX != row && neighbourY != col))
          numNeighbors = numNeighbors + 1
      }
    }
  }

  def receive = {

case Compare() => {
  for (neighbourX <- gridrow - 1 to gridrow + 1) {
    if (neighbourX >= 0 && neighbourX < col) {
      for (neighbourY <- gridcol - 1 to gridcol + 1) {
        if (neighbourY >= 0 && neighbourY < row && (neighbourX != row && neighbourY != col)) 
          sender ! Record(life, currentStep) //Here I need to pass messages to my neighbors
      }
    }
  }

}

case Record(alive,step) => {
  if(alive == true){
    count(step%2) += 1
  }
  countsuround(step%2) += 1
  self ! Check()
}

case Check() => {
  if(countsuround(currentStep%2) == numNeighbors) {

    if(count(currentStep%2) ==3 ||life == true && count(currentStep%2) == 2)
      life = true
    else
      life = false

    count(currentStep%2) =0; countsuround(currentStep%2) = count(currentStep%2)
    currentStep += 1

    if(desiredSteps <= currentStep + 1)
      sender ! Stop
    else {
      sender ! Done(gridrow, gridcol, alive)
      //context.stop(self)
    }
  }
}

  }

}
```

Please take a look at the Compare case in the receive function, at the end of that, I need to send messages Record to my neighbors, but I can't find a proper way to talk, I don't have any index of neighbors (like (neighborX, neighborY).Record(life, currentStep)). Please help me, I've stuck here for several weeks. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm still not sure if the code works, so if you think there is something wrong, please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working  example with some comments.

```
import akka.actor._
import scala.concurrent.duration._


object GameOfLife extends App {
    val system = ActorSystem("game-of-life")

    implicit val ec = system.dispatcher // implicit ExecutionContext for scheduler

    val Width  = 20
    val Height = 20

    // create view so we can send results to
    val view = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[View], Width, Height), "view")

    // create map of cells, key is coordinate, a tuple (Int, Int)
    val cells = (for { i <- 0 until Width; j <- 0 until Height } yield {
        val cellRef = system.actorOf(Props[Cell], s"cell_$i-$j") // correct usage of Props, see docs for details
        ((i,j), cellRef)
    }).toMap

    // we need some helpers to work with grid

    val neighbours = (x:Int, y:Int) => Neighbours(
        for (i <- x - 1 to x + 1; j <- y - 1 to y + 1; if ((i,j) != (x,y))) yield {
            cells( ( (i + Width) % Width, (j + Height) % Height) )
        }
    )

    for { i <- 0 until Width; j <- 0 until Height } { // notice that this loop doesn't have yield, so it is foreach loop
        cells((i,j)) ! neighbours(i,j) // send cell its' neighbours
    }

    // now we need to synchronously update all cells,
    // this is the main reason why suggested model (one actor - one cell) is probably not the most adequate

    for { i <- 0 until Width; j <- 0 until Height } {
      cells((i,j)) ! SetState(alive = util.Random.nextBoolean, x = i, y = j)
    }

    // for simplicity I assume that update will take less then update time
    val refreshTime = 100.millis

    system.scheduler.schedule(1.second, refreshTime) {
      view ! Run
      for { i <- 0 until Width; j <- 0 until Height } { 
        cells((i,j)) ! Run 
      }
    }


}


class View(w:Int, h:Int) extends Actor {

  var actorStates: Map[(Int,Int), Boolean] = Map()

  def receive:Receive = {
    case Run => actorStates = Map.empty
    case UpdateView(alive, x, y) =>
      actorStates = actorStates + (((x,y), alive))
      if (actorStates.size == w * h) {
        for { j <- 0 until h } {
          for(i <- 0 until w) {
            if(actorStates((i,j))) {
              print("x ")
            } else {
              print(". ")
            }
          }
          println()
        }
      }
  }
}

class Cell extends Actor {

    var neighbours:Seq[ActorRef] = Seq()
    var neighbourStates: Map[ActorRef, Boolean] = Map() //  Map.empty[Map[ActorRef, Boolean]] is better
    var alive:Boolean = false
    var previousState:Boolean = false
    var x:Int = 0
    var y:Int = 0

    def receive : Receive = {
      case Run =>
        neighbourStates = Map.empty
        previousState = alive
        neighbours.foreach(_ ! QueryState)
      case SetState(alive,x,y) =>
        this.alive = alive
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
      case Neighbours(xs) =>
        neighbours = xs

      case QueryState =>
        sender ! NeighbourState(alive = previousState)
      case NeighbourState(alive) =>
        neighbourStates = neighbourStates + ((sender, alive))
        // this is tricky when all senders has send you their states it doesn't mean that you can mutate your own, 
        // they could still may request your internal state, will use hackish previousState 
        if (neighbourStates.size == 8) { // total of 8 neighbours sent their states, we are complete with update
          val aliveMembers = neighbourStates.values.filter(identity).size
          aliveMembers match {
            case n if n < 2 => this.alive = false
            case 3 => this.alive = true
            case n if n > 3 => this.alive = false;
            case _ => // 2, state doesn't change
          }

          context.actorSelection("/user/view") ! UpdateView(this.alive, x, y)
        }
    }
}


case class SetState(alive:Boolean, x:Int, y:Int)
case class Neighbours(xs:Seq[ActorRef])
case object QueryState
case object Run
case class NeighbourState(alive:Boolean)
case class UpdateView (alive:Boolean, x:Int, y:Int)
```

Comment: I've tried your code, it does work, but not in a parallel ways. My thought is that creating actors and let them run parallel. One way to do that is using parallel collection I think, but is there any other way to create actors not using collection? For example, recursively creating actors, but if so, how to implement that and get neighbors without coordinate? :)

Comment: How do you mean not in parallel ways? It is 99.999% parallel with all computations being carried by message communication between actors)
Of course I have to wait for all actors to change their state before next update could be performed. To avoid this you can use immutable array of cells, then next update doesn't change state of the previous one so you can do this in a true parallel fashion, maybe with parallel collections. But then you don't need so many actors, in fact you won't need no actors at all.